# Загрузка двух моделей нейронной сети на сервер

Tags: python, flask, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь выложить 2 модели нейронной сети в веб приложение c помощью flask, при загрузке нужно указать граф модели, который работает для всего потока, для второй модели тоже вызывается этот граф и выходит ошибка о разной размерности. Этот метод может можно заменить get_default_graph()

```
# Загрузка модели
def load__model():
    """Load model once at running time for all the predictions"""
    global model1, model2
    global graph1, graph2


    model1 = load_model(MODEL_FOLDER + '/fine_tuned.h5')
    model2 = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

    graph1 = tf.get_default_graph()
    graph2 = tf.get_default_graph()

    print('[INFO] : Model loaded') 

# Метод predict, сюда передаю данные из load_model()

def predict(fullpath, model, graph, image_size):
    data = image.load_img(fullpath, target_size=(image_size, image_size, 3))
    data = image.img_to_array(data)
    # Scaling
    data = data.astype('float') / 255
    data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=0)

    # Prediction
    with graph.as_default():
        result = model.predict(data)
    return result

#вызываю метод 
pred1 = predict(fullname, model1, graph1, 256)
pred2 = predict(fullname, model2, graph2, 224)
```